# Re-stash changes that where suspended cause of other commits

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-stash

I have something messed up with a repository on two different machines.

On my machine (A) I committed some changes and wanted to have these on the other machine (B), but on the second one there were some changes that **I needed to backup and to be restored later**.

So I took a `git diff` to see where the changes were, and then `git stash` on machine B to clean the directory.
Finally I `git pull --rebase` the new commits and tested everything was working on the machine B.

**Then** I tried to **restore the stashed changes** doing a `git stash pop` (I usually prefer a `git stash apply` but in this case I didn't used it).

I received a

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (8d5ee9...aa3)
```

I then performed a `git status` and saw nothing was changed.

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

*"Mmmh... weird. I wanted to restore some changes that actually was changed and stashed"*

I thought to have lost the changes, so tried to do a `git apply 8d5ee9...af3`, but nothing changed.

*"Damn! Maybe there were nothing in the stash, for some weird reason!"*

Luckily I always keep all the log of the terminal and came back to the `git diff`, and saw what changes I had stashed.
I took a look at the files and I saw the stashed changes already integrated in the code, but `git status` was not telling me I had unstaged files.

*"What? Some kind of rebase/merge has happened and I don't even know when and how??"*

So I tried to `git checkout master` (cause the stashed changes should be detached from it), and I got a

```
Warning: you are leaving 109 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

   8d5ee94 WIP on (no branch): 2cffcf8 uses the service
   be1466a index on (no branch): 2cffcf8 uses the service
   2cffcf8 uses the service
   b8d40bf Added pagination
  ... and 105 more.

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so

Switched to branch 'master'
```

At this point I stopped to understand at all what was going on.

*"What the hell?? Why I have so many detached commits? I'm sure they must be coming from the 'master' branch..... but, how??"*

So I still have the changes from the stash inside the branch 'master'; I don't get it.. and don't know **how to detach the stashed changes, as before, and have them divided again from the actual master branch**

I tried a `git pull --rebase` + `git checkout master` on both machine A and B, but the files that were in the stash on B are still different respect to the same files on A.

**How can I have my initial situation?**

- The unknown changes in a stash (to eventually restore as unstaged changes)
- The branch to master with the commits I did after the stash

I'm actually confused on what to do.

---

## A brief list of the *git* commands typed:

1. `git status` **(Master -> Nothing to commit)**
2. `git stash pop` **(Master -> Nothing to commit) (Dropped stash{0}: commit a1b2c3d4)**
   (here I was expecting my changes to me shown as unstaged files)
3. `git stash apply a1b2c3d4`
   (not seeing any change I tried to apply it)
4. `git checkout a1b2c3d4` **(NoBranch, detached HEAD on a1b2c3d4 -> Nothing to commit)**
   (not seeing any change I stupidly tried this)
5. `git checkout master` **(Master -> Nothing to commit)**
   (the final stupid thing. So now everything is merged)
6. checked the files and the changes were there, but still not shown from `git status`

I want to come back to the first command status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the behaviour.

A colleague, working on the machine B, committed the changes that were in the stash, even if I don't know why the directory was not cleaned (maybe it moved the files and probably committed from somewhere else, a machine C ).
Anyway there were staged files I stashed (for not loosing unknown work from someone else) that corresponded to already committed changes.
So, pulling the most recent commits did already get the changes that I was trying to restore from the stash.

I probably made some mistake controlling the files on the machine A and I didn't see the changes were already there.

Sorry for wasting your time.

And I suggest everyone to eat something instead of keep hitting the head on a problem together with the hunger :)